# duplicate data from employees table

Tags: oracle

my code retrieves the highest salary and number of employees in a `job_id` that a user specifies. this is an SQL code in oracle 10g express edition, now what do you think should I put in the question mark on my code to create an exception handler that will detect when there are two employees that has the highest salary in the specified `job_id`... Please help me guys, what do you think is the keyword that I should use on the question mark in my exception section?

```
DECLARE

lvn_emp_tot    NUMBER;
lvn_max_sal    NUMBER;
lvc_jb_id      VARCHAR2(30) := :JOB_ID;


BEGIN

  SELECT job_id, max(salary), count(job_id)
    INTO lvc_jb_id, lvn_max_sal, lvn_emp_tot
    FROM Employees
   WHERE job_id = lvc_jb_id
   GROUP BY job_id; 

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Maximum salary:  '||lvn_max_sal);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of Employees: '||lvn_emp_tot);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN ? THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('More than one employee has the highest salary');

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before that change your query :

```
select job_ID,salary,count(*) INTO lvc_jb_id, lvn_max_sal, lvn_emp_tot 
from Employees
where salary= (
                 SELECT max(salary)
                 FROM Employees
                 WHERE job_id = input_jobid
                 GROUP BY job_id
              )
group by job_ID;
```

In declare block :

```
ex_custom EXCEPTION;
```

and after query :

```
if lvn_emp_tot>1 then
    raise ex_custom ;    
end if;
```

After all this :

`?=ex_custom` ;)

Comment: thanks Rahul but unfortunately that did not work. lvn_emp_tot counts the total employees in the specified job_id, not when more than one  employees have the highest salary in the same job_id.

Comment: i think i have missed group by job_ID now check with edited version